# Why can't you use the annotation @Param over only one parameter?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need to create a query over a JpaRepository and my method takes in 3 parameters but only 1 is used in the query( the other one is a Pageable)

Let's suppose my query is :

```
@Query(
        value="SELECT t FROM T t WHERE status = A AND (:B = :B) AND loginDate IS NULL",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(a) FROM T t WHERE status = :A AND (:B= :B) AND loginDate IS NULL")
Page<T> findAllByStatusAndLoginDateIsNull(@Param("A") A, @Param("B"), Pageable pageable )
```

The problem is that I'm obliged to use all my parameters, so I have to include the useless condition `:B = :B`. Is there a cleaner solution or workaround it?

I know I could create another method that doesn't take all three parameters, but let's say I want to keep my method this way.

Comment: `@Param("B"),` ... what is that? Why is there a comma? Even if that is a typo, why would you use `@Param("B") Pageable pageable`? There is no need to have that annotation there.

Comment: It's @Param("B"). I need the annotation to pass the parameters into the query (:B).

Comment: I wrote `@Param("B"),`, not `@Param("B")`. You also have no parameter B.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @Param("B") B.

Comment: When your question doesn't make sense to me. Why do you pass `B` to the method when you don't want to use it?

Comment: Because the method is already there and it's used elsewhere

Comment: Then fix that method. It makes no sense to have a method with X parameters when you don't use and don't care about some of them. If the other method passes `B` to `findAllByStatusAndLoginDateIsNull` then it either expects it to have a meaning, thus ignoring `B` is bad, or it doesn't bother about `B` as well, then remove that parameter.